# Поиск подстроки в Python RegEx с учетом парности скобок и без учета концов строк

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, latex

Мне нужно на Python в LaTeX-статьях находить содержимое определенных макрокоманд LaTeX с учетом парности скобок, но без учета одиночных знаков перевода строки. Например,

```
\title[Синтез знаний: проблемы и методы\ldots]{Синтез знаний: проблемы и методы 
при построении моделей интеллектуальных систем}

\abstractrus{Рассматриваются задачи использования {\it  регулярных структур} памяти
$\Sigma =\{\Sigma(z)  \vert z\in M\}$ 
и~$\tilde{\Sigma}  =  \{\tilde{\Sigma}(z)   \vert z\in R\}$ 
для моделирования процессов синтеза структур 
знаний с помощью операций обработки знаний из специальных классов 
таких операций. Эти структуры определяют форматы используемых подобластей памяти. 

Форматы областей соответствуют структурам элементов доменов
(областей определения и значения операций)...}

\abstracteng{Cybernetic principles considered as the basis for the development...}
```

Кратко по синтаксису. В LaTeX макрокоманды начинаются со знака `\`, затем, после названия макрокоманды, может следовать (а может и не следовать) необязательный параметр в паре квадратных скобок `[]`, а обязательный параметр — в паре фигурных скобок `{}`.  Также фигурные скобки используются для создания т.н. групп (что-то типа ограничения scope). Если же нужно вывести саму фигурную скобку, в тексте пишут, например, `\{`. LaTeX в процессе работы не учитывает множественные пробелы (они превращаются в один пробел) и одиночные переводы строк (также превращаются потом в один пробел). Новый абзац обозначается как два знака перевода строки. Это упрощенное описание синтаксиса LaTeX, но в моем случае оно полностью верно.

Мне нужна функция, возвращающая содержимое обязательного аргумента макрокоманды `word` из ранее прочитанного файла `file` типа

```
def tag(file, word): # file - содержимое LaTeX-файла, word - команда, содержимое которой парсим
    regex = re.compile(r'\\' + word + '\[?.*?\]?\{(.*)\}', re.MULTILINE)
    return regex.findall(file)
```

Эта функция хорошо работает только если содержимое нужной команды представляет собой одну отдельную строку (что логично), так как при использовании `re.DOTALL` видно, что она является слишком жадной. Мне же нужно, чтобы она не была ни слишком жадной, ни слишком ленивой и обязательно учитывала парность фигурных скобок, вложенность которых может быть довольно большой, а также игнорировала одинарные знаки конца строки (просто заменяла их на пробелы), но при этом два знака перевода строки превращала бы в одинарный знак конца строки.

То есть в результате мне нужно чтобы функция `tag(file,'abstractrus')` вернула

```
Рассматриваются задачи использования {\it регулярных структур} памяти $\Sigma =\{\Sigma(z) \vert z\in M\}$ и $\tilde{\Sigma} = \{\tilde{\Sigma}(z) \vert z\in M\}$ для моделирования процессов синтеза структур знаний с помощью операций обработки знаний из специальных классов таких операций. Эти структуры определяют форматы используемых подобластей памяти. 
Форматы областей соответствуют структурам элементов доменов (областей определения и значения операций)....
```

Буду благодарен за советы в построении нужного регулярно выражения.

Comment: "Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить. Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе. Если для вас программирование — лишний предмет в учебной программе, есть сайты и люди на этих сайтах, выполняющие задания за материальное вознаграждение. Здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — моветон." https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @СергейКох Благодарю за совет